# evaluating a sum with factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I evaluate this sum?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)!}$

I've tried by substituting $n+2=u$

Then:

$\sum_{u=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(u\right)!}=e-1-\frac{1}{2}=e-\frac{3}{2}$

Wrong result!

Comment: It’s $e-1-1$, not $e-1-\tfrac12$

Comment: I've completely forgotten that $0!=1$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac1{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^1\dfrac1{n!}=e-1-1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Don't be too fast. The development of $e$ is

$$\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots=1+1+\frac1{(0+2)!}+\frac1{(1+2)!}+\frac1{(2+2)!}+\cdots$$